# What clinical presentations are you seeing in Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, infectious-diseases

Many of us have yet to see a case.  What is your personal experience?

Comment: [What's the max length for a quote?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1153/43)

Comment: I'm reaching out to the original author on sermo to ask what the issue is here.  It's very odd if copyright was asserted since he asked that his post be shared widely.